# How can I make a gem perform an action on install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

**Update:**
Mainly, I need a .bat file to be placed in RUBY_HOME/bin, similar to how rails.bat gets placed in bin when the Rails gem is installed

I'm building a gem that can be used for generating automation test frameworks for testing web application written in any language, with any framework.

I need one file within my gem to be run every time the gem is installed. This file generates either a .bat or .sh file.

I have already built this script and it works great, I just need it be run each time the gem is installed using bundler. Is this possible?

Comment: sounds like a security concern - i wouldn't want a gem to execute arbitrary code on install.

Comment: What exactly is the reason for doing this? Perhaps you have other options.

Comment: The reason is so that I can call a command by name from command line

Comment: If it's not possible then I can just place instructions within the readme to tell the user 'hey guy, run the installer after you download the gem'

Comment: Mainly, I need a .bat file to be placed in RUBY_HOME/bin, similar to how `rails.bat` gets placed in bin when the Rails gem is installed